# Problem with loop

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

When a mousemove event is reaised the variable `i` is equal to last value(In my case = 4) for ALL sectors. Where i can store value of `i`?

```
for (var i = 0; i < pieChart.Sectors.length; i++) {
  pieChart.Sectors[i].mousemove(function (event) {
     var percent = (localData[i] * 100) / totalSum;
     pieChart.Popup(event.clientX, event.clientY, [percent, "% всего времени\n Было сделано", localData[i], "звонков"].join(' '));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a closure. See here for a nice explanation: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

I'll be posting your code modified shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Answered like a thousand times, 1001 answers: Your event handler functions will *close* over the `i` variable. That means, all functions reference the same variable and therefore all of them have the identical value.

Solution: Introduce a new function(-context):

```
pieChart.Sectors[i].mousemove((function (myEvent) {
        return function() {
            var percent = (localData[i] * 100) / totalSum;
            // do something with "myEvent"
        };
}(event)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you variable `$i` had been declared as a global variable before.

You can even check this with an `alert(window.i);` or `console.log(window.i);` at any time.